# How can I reduce the cost of method initialization in C#?

Tags: c#, optimization, profiling

I'm in the process of writing a caching partial-sort structure such that subsequent searches of the same structure take advantage of prior searches. This is expected to need to work pretty snappily with large collections (1m+ items), so having got everything essentially working, I'm trying to profile it down.

In the course of so doing, I encountered the below method which is apparently - at least in Debug compiled code - using around 17% of total execution time on initialising the method (17% next to the first `{` character), which feels like a lot. The code is being called frequently, and in release mode I'd expect it to get inlined, but given the below, I can't work out what initialization is actually taking place - all variables accessed and modified are fields in the overall `struct` which represents the search.

Can anyone spot places where the C# compiler might feel the need to create variables in place of syntactic sugar etc. in the below, or otherwise help me understand why the initialization cost of this method is roughly the same as its execution in total? (Circa 11% for the first loop, 4% for the second).

Worth noting that `_p_Items_SortedFlag` is a pointer to the first item in a boolean array, and everything else are `int`s.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private void StepBackToUnsorted()
{
    // Step the RCursor back to the last unsorted item
    // Costs circa 11% on the while conditions.
    while (_p_Items_SortedFlag[_RCursor] && _RCursor > _LCursor)
    {
        --_RCursor;
        ++_RCount;
    }

    // Step the Upper Right bound through any sorted
    // items
    // Costs Circa 4% on the while conditions.
    while (_p_Items_SortedFlag[_RUpper] && _RUpper > _RCursor)
        --_RUpper;
}
```

As mentioned, this code probably ends up inlined on release. However, I'm still very interested - from a how-can-I-avoid-it-when-it-isn't-inlined perspective - as to what could be causing such a large initialization cost for something like this where literally everything should just be there waiting for use.

Comment: Have you tried passing the built code through a decompiler to see what's actually generated? I've found that useful sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean: *_p_Items_SortedFlag is a pointer to the first item in a boolean array*? `_p_Items_SortedFlag` is an array when I look at your code.

Comment: This code gets called only within a loop, just before which I call `fixed (bool* p = _Items_SortedFlag) {_p_Items_SortedFlag = p; ....`. The idea being to fix the memory for the array once and then reduce overhead of assigning locals versus using a shared field. Cuts my overall execution time in half, roughly.

Comment: Haven't yet tried decompiling the code, to be fair. I'll run it through ILSpy this evening to see what it's doing...